# Is the GROUP BY needed to insert

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
    (Street,
     Number,
     NuDate,
     XValue)
SELECT
     a1.Street,
     a2.Number,
     a2.NuDate,
     a2.XValue
FROM
    ABC.dbo.Faculty a1 INNER JOIN
    ABC.dbo.Faculty2  a2
    ON a1.NameID = a2.NameID
WHERE
    a1.Bologna = 'True'
GROUP BY
     a1.Street,
     a2.Number,
     a2.NuDate,
     a2.XValue
```

In this completely fictitious SQL statement, is the GROUP by needed to insert properly into NEWTABLE?  and/or does the group by need to match up perfectly with the INSERT INTO for this statement to work properly?

EDIT: Sorry, I realized I had the wrong values for the GROUP BY statement, they're supposed to match the INSERT INTO

Comment: you cannot use columns in SELECT part which are not part of GROUP BY (except aggregated functions), so this query is blatantly wrong

Comment: "It depends" (on both the requirements and the available data). As we have no stated requirements or any sample data/expected result, this question has no definitive answer. As already stated the shown query is invalid also. Suggest you reconsider the question.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. What are you trying to do? A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> In this completely fictitious SQL statement, is the GROUP by needed to insert properly into NEWTABLE?

1. It's not necessary if you don't mind duplicates
2. If you don't want duplicate rows then yes, you'll need to use GROUP BY (or DISTINCT):

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
    a1.Street,
    a2.Number,
    a2.NuDate,
    a2.XValue
   ```

> does the group by need to match up perfectly with the INSERT INTO for this statement to work properly?

Yes, the selected columns must match.

There are cases when what you group by doesn't match what you select but that's when you aggregating:

```
SELECT 
column1, -- no aggregation, must match
sum(column2) -- aggregation, so does not need to match
FROM a
GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized I had entered the wrong values in the GROUP BY. I actually wanted them to match the INSERT INTO and SELECT statement.